# System.ArgumentNullException: 'Value cannot be null.Parameter name: value'

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, visual-studio, model-view-controller

## System.ArgumentNullException: 'Value cannot be null.Parameter name: value'

Hello everyone, I encountered an error in my program that I cannot solve
this is my controller code:

```
 public ActionResult AddComment(int id, string email,string name,string comment)
        {
            PageComment addcomment = new PageComment()
            {
                CreateDate = DateTime.Now,
                Name = name,
                Email = email,
                Comment = comment,
                PageID = id,
            };
            pagecommetRepository.AddComment(addcomment);
            return View();
        }
```

and my service code:

```
 public bool AddComment(PageComment comment)
        {
            
            try
            {
                db.pageComments.Add(comment);
                db.SaveChanges();
                return true;
            }
            catch (Exception)
            {
                
                return false;
            }
        }
```

Give me this error when it tries to save
Of course, when it is not in try, when it is in try, it does not save the information in the database

## System.ArgumentNullException: 'Value cannot be null.Parameter name: value'

Comment: Please [edit] your post with a [mre]. I'm _assuming_ your error is saying the `comment` variable is null, which doesn't make sense given the code you've posted.

Comment: When you debug, which specific operation produces this error?  What are the exact observed runtime values used in that operation?  What result did you expect?  Why?

Comment: When I try to save, it gives this error if I don't have a variable called value

Comment: And my variables all have values, but one is null, which is nullable, and one is page, which I didn't count among the variables at all. (((public virtual Page page { get; set; })))) And when the codes are in try, it doesn't produce an exception anymore, but the information is not saved in the database

Comment: You added a null value to name, causing the error to appear. Add validation to all parameters, make sure everything is valid before you send it to the service.

Comment: You can make a non-null judgment before creating the PageComment object, and you can proceed to the next step when there is no null value, which can effectively prevent this error

Comment: Excuse me, can you show me the code?

Answer (score 0):

```
public ActionResult AddComment(int id, string email,string name,string comment)
{
    try {

        // Validate inputs before passing to service
        if (String.IsNullOrEmpty(email) || String.IsNullOrEmpty(name) || String.IsNullOrEmpty(comment)) { 
            return new HttpStatusCodeResult(HttpStatusCode.BadRequest);
        }
    
        PageComment addcomment = new PageComment()
        {
            CreateDate = DateTime.Now,
            Name = name,
            Email = email,
            Comment = comment,
            PageID = id,
        };
    
        if (pagecommetRepository == null)
        {
            return new HttpStatusCodeResult(HttpStatusCode.BadRequest);
        }
        pagecommetRepository.AddComment(addcomment);
        return View();

    catch (Exception)
    {
        // 
    }
    return new HttpStatusCodeResult(HttpStatusCode.BadRequest);
}
```

Service:

```
public bool AddComment(PageComment comment)
{
    try
    {
        if (comment == null) {
            return false;
        }
        if (db == null) {
            return false;
        }
        
        db.pageComments.Add(comment);
        db.SaveChanges();
        return true;

    }
    catch (Exception)
    {           
        //
    }
    return false;
}
```

Comment: @abolfazl Check the value of all parameters (email, name and comment) before entering PageComment. Are all the parameters valid or null? If either is null, the service will never be executed.

Comment: I checked that they all have value

Comment: @abolfazl I've added validation for all object parameters and added a try catch. Debug your program, notice they go to catch when executing which line? that's where the error occurs.

Comment: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/get-started/csharp/tutorial-debugger?view=vs-2022